# Paypal integration with PHP without logging into the PayPal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, payment, checkout

we want to integrate the PHP with Paypal payment. As we have the Paypal business account and we want to integrate this payment with our ecommerce website. And we have tried the following code.

```
 <?php

                    // $x = 0;
                    $y = $this->session->userdata('sub_total');

                    $discounttotal = $this->session->userdata('discount_total');
                      // $tax = $this->session->userdata('tax');
                    $shipping = $this->session->userdata('shipping');
                      $final_amount = $this->session->userdata('final_amount');
                      $z=0;
?>

<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script>
  paypal.Button.render({
    // Configure environment
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
      sandbox: 'AetxekWctvziIYR4_YnKYCE7NjzwNV1duPwtOKYzjjly3Cgc4-TpaGhdeVlXY-4bRufu_S8tN9ZHdra_',
      production: 'demo_production_client_id'
    },
    // Customize button (optional)
    locale: 'en_IN',
    style: {
      size: 'small',
      color: 'gold',
      shape: 'pill',
    },

    // Enable Pay Now checkout flow (optional)
    commit: true,

    // Set up a payment
    payment: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.payment.create({
        transactions: [{
          amount: {
            total: <?php echo $final_amount;?>,
            currency: 'INR'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    // Execute the payment
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
        // Show a confirmation message to the buyer
        /*for (var propertyName in data) {
          //alert( propertyName + " : " + data[propertyName] );
        }*/
        window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
        $("form").submit();
      });
    }
  }, '#paypal-button');

</script>
```

While running the code, paypal button is appearing on the page and when we click it redirects to the PayPal login page. Here is the problem, if the user doesn't have the paypal account, how the payment will be done. Is there any chance to accept the payment through credit/debit cards, mobile wallets, so that the amount will be added to our paypal amount. Please suggest me the right way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Smart Payment Buttons, so buyers in many countries across the world would be able to pay directly with a credit/debit card by clicking the black button on the page.

But some countries, like India, don't have this. The regular PayPal checkout will open, and they will need to either sign in or sign up for an account.

If you are concerned about the experience of a customer with no existing PayPal account, you should test the flow in a private/incognito browser or one with no paypal.com cookies storing an email address.  You will find that the flow to enter a credit card and then choose a password and check a box at the bottom to create the PayPal account instantaneously as part of the process, is not complicated

Comment: thank you for reply, as per your reply, in India, we don't have the black button. But how the user without paypal account will complete by credit/debit card in India, will you please explain briefly

Comment: Essentially PayPal will ask for all their card details, and then also ask them to choose a password.  When they click to "Accept & Pay", they will be sending the credit/debit card payment to you *and* creating a new PayPal account instantaneously, all at the same

Comment: Thank you for reply. Will you please provide any references for integrating.

Comment: we have a doubt that we have created paypal account but we haven't completed the KYC for bank details. Is it necessary to complete KYC to use sandbox payments too?

Comment: No, the sandbox is all fake information; as long as you are able to log into https://www.paypal.com/signout?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F , you can then create unlimited sandbox accounts for testing.  Usually you just need a business one to receive payments and a personal one to test checkouts with.